# How to convert a rake task into a simple function call in a ROR application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake-task

I am new in ROR, so my question is probably easy. However, I would like to explain my state.

I have a ruby **project1** which serves as a library. From this project I am interested in 1 rake task with this specific form:

```
rake function1: function2 [arg1, arg2]
```

Then, I am implementing another ROR application, where I would like to include the **project1**, and call somewhere in a  my libs, the functions from **projects1** rake tasks, because I need its functionality.

Can anyone provide me a guidance of some information how I can call these functions? Should I search in the code and call the corresponding functions? Is there an easier way?

Comment: don't use semicolon, use space seprated rake tasks

Comment: So you want to migrate the code from one app to the other? Or would you like to *call* the function from the first app in the second app?

Comment: I would like to migrate it

Comment: Create a gem with the functionality from `project1` and then include it into your rails app. http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of ways of including code from one project in another project.

One of the popular ways is Ruby gems. The core idea is that you package your code into a gem, which is standalone library. You then include your gem in your various projects.

Another popular way, if you're using git, is to create a git repository with the code you want to share. You then add the repo as a git submodule in your various projects. You also put the repo's directory on the load path for the rake tasks (or you require the particular files by a relative path).

In my experience, gems take somewhat more time to set up and maintain, and when you change gem code, you must publish a new gem version. Whereas git submodules are fast and easy. I suggest you try both and see which approach you prefer.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your reply. I checked again the project1 and it can be included as a gem to another project. I also checked the project1.gemspec, and I notice that in the Gem::Specification files I have access also to the rakefiles and all the available folders of the project. So now my question is: Is it good and possible to call rake files from a gem? and if yes can you provide me a link, so I can work like that? Maybe your experience can help me avoiding mistakes!

Comment: Yes, it's fine to call rake tasks that come from another gem. For a link, take a look at the Devise authentication gem, which is a Rails engine, and which provides its own rake tasks for migrations.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I see better what I would like to dl, so I am going to open a new question